# eval.call throws error in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

My Chrome extension includes a JS library, loaded in local. When I run the extension I have this error:

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'

This error because in the library script there is:

```
module.exports = function(src) {
  if (typeof execScript !== "undefined")
    execScript(src);
  else
    eval.call(null, src);
}
```

Then the instruction `eval.call(null, src)` causes the error.

I have tried to include this directive in manifest V3, but I have the same error:

```
"content_security_policy": {
  "extension_page": "self",
  "script-src": "self",
  "object-src": "self"
}
```

Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: You'll need to rewrite that library. Why does it use eval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written in the Chrome Developers documentation, the eval() function is disabled to ensure users safety:

> Chrome's extension system enforces a fairly strict default Content Security Policy (CSP). The policy restrictions are straightforward: script must be moved out-of-line into separate JavaScript files, inline event handlers must be converted to use addEventListener, and eval() is disabled.

You can read more about it from Chrome Developers documentations here:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/sandboxingEval/